# SharePoint 2016 Outbound Email

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-email, outgoing-email, exchange

SharePoint 2016 email notifications does not work. I followed all the steps in [this](https://www.sharepointsapiens.com/calendar-email-extension/documentation/configure-sharepoint-e-mail/) article and successfully configured everything. When I use **telnet** I can send emails with the same settings, but I dont get **alerts** from list changes or **workflow emails** (workflow completes without an error).

Additional Info: I am the site admin, and I have enabled alerts for all the changes on a list, but I do not get any, workflow emails either. I also tried [this script](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/256157/42680), it also returns false. (Telnet works with the same settings)

I really appreciate any help on how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should start by tracing messages on the SMTP server to identify why the mail messages are not succeeding when sent from the PowerShell you linked to. It may be due to relay restrictions on the SMTP server.

You can also check the SharePoint ULS log at the time you send the email via PoSh to see if there are additional useful errors. I believe you can filter by Category Contains `Mail` in `ulsviewer`.